# Setting up Processing for Android development environment

Tags: android, processing

I'm trying to set up a development environment with processing for android.

I followed all the instructions for SDK installation *and* processing, but I'm still unable to compile builtin examples.

In Linux I get:

```
    BUILD FAILED
/home/poko/android-studio/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:962: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/poko/android-studio/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:973: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/poko/android-studio/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:313: com.android.sdklib.build.ApkCreationException: Failed to create key: Cannot run program "/home/poko/Downloads/software/processing-2.1/java/bin/keytool": error=2, No such file or directory
JAVA_HOME is set to: /home/poko/Downloads/software/processing-2.1/java
Update it if necessary, or manually execute the following command:
/home/poko/Downloads/software/processing-2.1/java/bin/keytool -genkey -alias AndroidDebugKey -keyalg RSA -dname "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US" -validity 10950 -keypass android -keystore /home/poko/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.getDebugKey(ApkBuilder.java:300)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:392)
    at com.android.ant.ApkBuilderTask.execute(ApkBuilderTask.java:334)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:124)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:124)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at processing.mode.android.AndroidBuild.antBuild(AndroidBuild.java:415)
    at processing.mode.android.AndroidBuild.build(AndroidBuild.java:73)
    at processing.mode.android.AndroidMode.handleRunDevice(AndroidMode.java:220)
    at processing.mode.android.AndroidEditor$14.run(AndroidEditor.java:310)

Total time: 14 seconds
```

Notice two things: JAVA_HOME is set to jdk directory on my linux box. But processing says JAVA_HOME is set to: /home/poko/Downloads/software/processing-2.1/java, which is the own processing java distribution.
Second thing is that keytool command is not present in processing own distribution of java.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.

Workaround is to execute keytool command manually. Cause its needs to be done just once. notice that output is telling you about that:

```
, or manually execute the following command:
/home/poko/Downloads/software/processing-2.1/java/bin/keytool -genkey -alias AndroidDebugKey -keyalg RSA -dname "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US" -validity 10950 -keypass android -keystore /home/poko/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android
```

You just need to change path to your correct java path
from:

```
/home/poko/Downloads/software/processing-2.1/java
```

To (Using JAVA_HOME if its set properly in your system)

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -genkey -alias AndroidDebugKey -keyalg RSA -dname "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US" -validity 10950 -keypass android -keystore /home/poko/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android
```

or just replace $JAVA_HOME with correct java path. In my case it was /usr/lib/jvm/default-java, I'm using KXStudio based on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS.

Don't know how to fix it cleaner way ATM. Will let you know if I will figure it out.

Comment: I,m using Processing 2.1 + Android SDK Tools 18 updated to -> 20